# VB Validate TextBox input to be Binary Number

Tags: vb6

I am trying to validate the input of a TextBox to make sure it is a Binary Number.  What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Dim b() As Byte
 b = Text1.Text

 If Not IsByte (b) Then
    Text3 = "Wrong input"
    Else
    Text3 = "CRC is generated"
  '  checksum.Text = Text1.Text Xor Text2.Text
   ' Trans(2).Text = (Text1.Text) + (checksum.Text)
 End If
```

Input in Text1 should only be accepting binary numbers, so only `1` or `0` should be allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Like` here:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If Len(Text1.Text) = 0 Or Text1.Text Like "*[!0-1]*" Then
        MsgBox "bad binary string"
    Else
        MsgBox "good binary string"
    End If
End Sub
```

This pattern is testing for "0 to many of anything, followed by one character not in the range 0 through 1, then 0 to many of anything."

Answer (score 0):

Even i cant find the function to check binary data. But cant you just check like

```
   If textbox1.text = 1 or textbox1.text = 2
```

I think you can also do with instr function.

Comment: yeah thank you its works, then how to initialize Text1 As Long?

Comment: can you accept the answer which will increase your reputation as well?

Comment: Accepting answer doesnt require any reputation. Its only upvoting that needs reputation. Please accept answer which shows your trust in people here. Just click on the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code. Request you to kindly google before posting any questions to this forum.

```
'will only allow 0 and 1
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
 Select Case KeyAscii
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey1
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub

' will validate if its numeric and you can further check for 0 or 1
Private Sub Command1_Click()
        If Not IsNumeric(Text1.Text) Then
            MsgBox "Please enter numbers only.", vbInformation
            'you may also consider erasing it
            Text1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: @Ricky-2135 your mozilla crashed but still you managed to post this question to stack overflow.

Comment: @Ricky-2135 kindly accept this answer before your mozilla or chrome crashes.

Comment: I want to but then its said need 15 reputations to vote, so sorry i just register today

Comment: @Ricky-2135 no worries :-)

Comment: this would be the answer i would go with